# Any downside to putting a button inside of an anchor?

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress plugin to add FB, Twitter, and LinkedIn share buttons to a post. I know it's been done a hundred times, but it's good practice and I'm putting a spin on it. Are there any downsides to putting a button inside of an anchor tag like so?

```
<a href="#"><input type="submit" value="share to facebook" /></a>
```

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is forbidden by the HTML specification
2. Some browsers will cause the link to break
3. Some browsers will cause the button to break

If you want a link that looks like a button, then use a link and apply CSS.

If you want a submit button, then don't put it inside a link.

Comment: wasn't aware of the breakage issue. I was just looking for a shortcut. The plugin I'm using allows the user to enter custom css to modify the button appearance. Was looking for a way to get the button without applying my style and then their's on top of it.